# find the count of num column changing by id

Tags: sas

Please can anyone help me the follwing probelm.

I have following dummy data:

```
id  num   
1   1
1   2
1   1
1   2
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   15
2   1 
2   1
2   1
2   15
2   1
2   15
```

How to count number of times num (column) is changing for each id?
Please find the results and new column.
I need results like this

```
id  number  no_of_times
1   1       1
1   2       1
1   1       1
1   2       2
1   1       1
1   2       3
2   1       1
2   15      1
2   1       1   
2   1       1
2   1       1
2   15      2
2   1       1
2   15      3
```

Hope you can understand after seeing the results

Comment: From the sample data you've provided, it isn't clear what logic you want to use. Please could you explain in words?

Comment: Why doesn't no_of_times go "1 2 1" for the first 3 observations in your example?

Comment: Hi 

here its like back anfd forth. 1 is back and 2 is forth

we need to count only forth ,how many times its going to forth.

each id:

so when it is first time changing 1 to 2 means no of times 1 for 1 and 2 for 1

if it goes to back(1)1 that means no change but value is 1 
if it goes again 1 to 2 that mean second times it is going to forth(2) so value 1 for 1 and  2 for 2

if it goes to back(1)1 that means no change but value is 1 

if it goes again 1 to 2 that mean second times it is going to forth(2) so value 1 for 1 and 2 for 3

hope it make sense.

Thank you

Comment: What if for a single ID it goes 1 > 2 > 1 > 3 > 1 > 2... what's the count at the '3' and the second '2'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following hash approach works for the test data provided with the question:

```
data have;
input id  number  no_of_times_target;
cards;
1   1       1
1   2       1
1   1       1
1   2       2
1   1       1
1   2       3
2   1       1
2   15      1
2   1       1   
2   1       1
2   1       1
2   15      2
2   1       1
2   15      3
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    length prev_number no_of_times 8;
    declare hash h();
    rc = h.definekey('number','prev_number');
    rc = h.definedata('no_of_times');
    rc = h.definedone();
  end;
  prev_number = lag(number);
  if number > prev_number and not(first.id) then do;
    rc = h.find();
    no_of_times = sum(no_of_times,1);
    rc = h.replace();
  end;
  else no_of_times = 1;
  if last.id then rc = h.clear();
  drop rc prev_number;
run;
```